# I don't have luck on my side, but I have fortune on my side. Who am I? And why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

- Hi. My name is six letters long.

---

- Sometimes, women try to avoid me for fear of something – not for fear of me, mind you! But they find it hard to resist me and my charming tanned body.
- As weird as it may sound, people love the wrinkles on my face.
- I can withstand the scorching desert-like heat – but not for too long! On the other hand, I'm no good in water. Don't expect me to dive into the sea!
- I'm an American with a capital A. When I visited the UK, the people there gave me funny looks. But once I changed my name to seven letters long, they became friendly all of a sudden.
- I don't have luck on my side, but I have fortune on my side.
- There's this nifty little gadget used to change me into attractive shapes that I like, but for some reason, if I use it, people criticises me for losing originality and becoming mundane. The gadget is called "my name + six letters long". {****** ******}
- I have physical form, but the other me below is like a ghost.

---

- You try to erase me from your memory, and you may feel lighter at heart for a while. But I'll be back every time and start to weigh you down again.
- Some people say nasty things to me, like "Don't stalk me!". But it's all a misunderstanding.
- My grandmother has me confused with the other me above. But you don't, right? I mean, seeing as you're here? I have faith in you.

Comment: Hi, Six Letters Long. I'm Dad.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its a

> Cookie

The title was a give-away

For the why part-

> I'm an American with a capital A. When I visited the UK, the people there gave me funny looks. But once I changed my name to seven letters long, they became friendly all of a sudden.

Brits call it

> Biscuit

Also

> I don't have luck on my side, but I have fortune on my side.

Which refers to

> Fortune Cookies

Here is more evidence

> here's this nifty little gadget used to change me into attractive shapes that I like, but for some reason, if I use it, people criticises me for losing originality and becoming mundane. The gadget is called "my name + six letters long". {****** ******}

That happens to be

> Cookie Cutter

The hint that blew the cover

> You try to erase me from your memory, and you may feel lighter at heart for a while. But I'll be back every time and start to weigh you down again.

If you have a computer and you are computer-literate, which I suppose you are

> You know how clearing Cookies, speeds up things.

**Edit, Consolidating all hints**

> As weird as it may sound, people love the wrinkles in my face.

May refer to

> The crusts and choco-chips on the cookie.

Also, Clue 9 and 10 correspond to this, I presume...

> (9)Some people think that cookies are used to snoop on other people's information on the web, but they are extremely handy for creating and managing sessions etc.
>  (10) Grandmothers think we are talking about the cookie referred above i.e. biscuits, but since you are at StackOverflow, the OP considers that you are able to differentiate between a cookie in your jar and one in your browser and temp folder.

Also

> Sometimes, women try to avoid me for fear of something – not for fear of me, mind you! But they find it hard to resist me and my charming tanned body.

They try to avoid

> Cookies, for the fear of getting fat. but they love it too.

And for this one

> I can withstand the scorching desert-like heat – but not for too long! On the other hand, I'm no good in water. Don't expect me to dive into the sea!

This implies that

> Cookies may withstand heat but too much heat may melt it's chocolates, while when it comes to water, cookies just become soluble.

And this one

> I have physical form, but the other me below is like a ghost.

Which is..

> The hints are divided into two parts, 1st for the Cookie i.e. Biscuit aka Wafers, the other is for Cookie aka message given to a Web browser by a Web server.

As for the **American with a capital A**, I am unable to find any relevance so far. Maybe, I need some Great American Cookie help.

Comment: Hats off to you! I didn't expect THE thing described in the title to be so readily deducible. That clue was meant to be vaguer than the others. To add the finishing touch, could you add to your answer what the second, fourth, and tenth clues each refer to? Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Actually, I meant the "women avoid me" clue as the second, not the first. Sorry I didn't make my way of counting clearer. At any rate, I was hoping you could fill in solutions to the remaining clues that you have yet to touch on. Perfect reasoning for computer cookies! As to the "wrinkle" clue, the reasoning is much simpler, actually. Thank you again.

Comment: I think the "You try to erase me from your memory, and you may feel lighter at heart for a while. But I'll be back every time and start to weigh you down again." might not be a computer reference but the denial and guilt people feel after eating lots of cookies, then do exercise to loose the weight associated with the cookies but ultimately they succumb to the sweets again.

Comment: @Brad          Although I meant this particular clue to be computer-related, I'm surprised to see that your interpretation holds up perfectly, too.

Comment: @Prashant      Simply marvellous! As for the "capital A" bit, I just meant it as "an American through and through" to indicate that the ANSWER is American stuff.

Comment: @MilFille This was actually the very first thing I thought of when I read the title. I didn't follow up with that instinct when reading the puzzle, though!